# 1min stock market data resample to over 1 hour with output giving incorrect start time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling, quantitative-finance

I am trying to downsample 1 min stock market data to multiple intraday timeframes.

I am new to all of this coding and stackoverflow so please bear with me.
Initially, I resampled the 1min data to 5, 30, and 45min increments with no problem. Then when I tried to downsample to 1hour increments the output was starting at a time index that was not in the original 1min data set; it would start at 9:00:00 when the earliest index in the data set is 9:31:00. After some searching I found that the solution to this issue is to include 'base=30' inside the .resample() function.

## Sample Code:

```
newDf = df.resample('60min', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

(SIDE NOTE: This code gives the correct output ONLY if the resample rate is input in a minute form, not hourly... '60min' = works, '1h' = doesn't work. Any explanation as to why would be appreciated but this is not my main question.)

I tried it, and it worked.

However, when I try to downsample anything over '60min', the output is wrong and the dateime index start moves back to a datetime that does not exist in the original 1min data set. I tried playing with the 'base=60' parameter and it didn't work. I then tried to use 'loffset=90' and was able to successfully get the output to begin at the correct datetime of 9:30:00 like the other resamples I had done but the values (open, high, low, close, etc) were inconsistent when compared with the original 1min data set.

## works

```
new5minDf = df.resample('5t', closed='right').agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

## works

```
new45minDf = df.resample('45min', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

## works

```
new60minDf = df.resample('60min', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

## DOES NOT WORK

```
new60minDf = df.resample('1h', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

## DOES NOT WORK

```
new120minDf = df.resample('2h', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

## DOES NOT WORK

```
new120minDf = df.resample('120t', closed='right', base=30 ).agg(dict(open='first', high='max', low='min', close='last', volume='sum', vwap='mean'))
```

To the best of my knowledge, I believe that the resample is using the first part of the day to output the the truncated resampled data. In other words, if I try to resample to 2h or 120min there will be one index location for each individual day that only contains 30min of data points. This is due to the length of a regular stock market trading session being 6.5 hours long. 6.5h or 390min is not evenly dividable by 2h or 120min so there will be one index that is actually shorter in data points than the other indexes for each individual day.

In traditional trading platforms like tradingview.com, the truncated data will show up on at the end of the day (the 2h data starts at 15:30:00 and ends at 16:00:00) and not the beginning of the day. When I'm resampling the truncated data is showing up in the opposite fashion (2h truncation happens between 9:30:00 and 10:00:00) even if I use loffset to give the correct starting datetime.
How can I fix the resample index inaccuracy to not only downsample into a 2h time frame with the output starting at the correct datetime (9:30:00) but also, the truncated period showing up at the end of the day (for 2h and 3h it would be 15:30:00-16:00:00, for 4h it would be 13:30:00-16:00:00 etc). I want to be able to resample any timeframe correctly, not just the ones mentioned. If I wanted to do a 33min or 65min or 2day or 5 week resample, I would like to know how to proceed given the desired output describe above. I am stressing this because the '60min, base=30' solution only worked for the 1h resample and not any larger time frames. Thank you for your time and effort. I am new to all of this and I appreciated the help.

p.s.
I tried to paste one days worth of 1min data from my data set so that you guys can use it to achieve the desired results but it ended up being too many characters so I had to remove it. If having access the data set will help and there's another way to share it on here, just let me know.